# distribution of 'median difference' in permutation test

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, central-limit-theorem, permutation-test

Recently, I want to apply the permutation test to find out if the difference of median for sample1 and sample2 has difference. Sample1 variance is 3.225248, and 
Sample2 variance is 0.1451835.

In my R script (shown below), there are two ways to compute the two tailed test p-value, one is `sum(abs(c(ts, reps)) >= ts)/10000` (method1: p.permutation), the other is `2*pnorm(-abs((ts-mean(c(reps,ts)))/sd(c(reps,ts))))` (method2: pnorm.permutation).

```
sample1 <-c(2.091010,3.036059,2.369857,2.790261,2.125939,
2.485093,3.296420,1.693960,10.024789,2.389982,
2.146223,6.050272,3.123362,4.017784,3.384869,
2.785430,3.324644,3.508125,2.163249,2.152928,
4.516797,2.544884)

sample2 <-  c(2.369857,1.986323,2.295646,2.004719,
1.657720,2.123288,2.224683,2.019223,
2.159055,3.107814,1.904748,1.701138,1.681909)

ts <- median(sample1) - median(sample2)
R <- 9999
all <- c(sample1, sample2)
k <- 1:length(all)
reps <- numeric(R)
p.permutation=c()
pnorm.permutation=c()
n=1
while(n<=9999){
 for (i in 1:R) {
   m <- sample(k, size=length(sample1), replace=FALSE)
   permsample1 <- all[m]
   permsample2 <- all[-m]
   reps[i] <- median(permsample1) - median(permsample2)
 }
 hist(reps)
 p.permutation[n]=sum(abs(c(ts, reps)) >= ts)/10000
 pnorm.permutation[n]=2*pnorm(-abs((ts-mean(c(reps,ts)))/sd(c(reps,ts))))
 n=n+1
}

hist(p.permutation)

hist(pnorm.permutation)
```

But I find after 9999 iterations. The distribution of p-value  between method1 and method2 has dramatically difference.

figure1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPTrY.png

figure2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwBsD.png

[image: p.permutation distribution]
[image: pnorm.permutation distribution]

The distribution of median difference (variable `reps` in the script) seem not to fit a normal distribution. [image: median difference distribution]

My questions are:

1. > A problem with doing a permutation test of equality of means occurs if you think that the possible difference in variance of the two groups will remain even if the null of equal means is true. ([Permutation testing](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204813/permutation-testing))

If the difference in variance of the two sample groups remain even, could distribution of **median difference** be normal distribution? In my example, distribution of **median difference** is not normal distribution, am I right?

I find a post of sample medians distribution:  [Central limit theorem for sample medians](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45124/central-limit-theorem-for-sample-medians), does anybody can help me to understand the medians difference distribution base on it?

2. which method is the correct way to compute p-value of permutation test? When could I use the method2? In my opinion, I think only method1 is correctly, but some one tell me method2 is right. I want to know how to explain the difference between method1 and method2.

**For method2, We are not comparing the absolute values of our simulated values to the actual difference of medians, please don not stop think the question when you see the comments below our post. Thanks.**

Comment: (1) None of your images can be viewed: the site says they have errors.  (2) There's at least one coding error; you're not consistent in your use of `abs`. (3) You don't need $9999\times 9999 \approx 10^8$ iterations to work this out--and requiring your readers to expend that much computation just to understand your question is asking far too much.  Please, therefore, *describe* the results you are getting *in words* if you wish to get useful answers.

Comment: @whuber thank you, (1) I will change my figures. (2) in the method2 , my friend use a trick when compute p-value, we also can use this formula `(1-pnorm(abs((ts-mean(c(reps,ts)))/sd(c(reps,ts)))))*2` , to make us easier to understand. (3) the `for (i in 1:R)` loop iterations is used to compute permutation p-value. the `while(n<=9999)` is used to show the two method p-value distribution. we can change them to other numbers.

Comment: It's not a trick--the purpose of that formula is obvious.  I was referring to the fact that you are comparing the absolute values of your simulated values to the actual difference of medians: `sum(abs(c(ts, reps)) >= ts)`.  Something is wrong with that--and I suspect it might have a lot to do with the discrepancy you observe.  BTW, it's unnecessary to produce these histograms of p-values.  They are irrelevant.  If you really want them, $50$ iterations will be plenty.

Comment: @LijiaYu Why do you concatenate `ts` in your vector of permuted means when calculating the p-value?

Comment: @AdamO  Actually, We want to add a 1 to the numerator and denominator to account for misestimation of the p-value, at here we just use the `ts` (although it isn't the maximum) https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21044043

Comment: @whuber sorry to make you misunderstand, `pvalue2sided=2*pnorm(-abs(z-score))`, we have a extra `()` in `2*pnorm(-abs((ts-mean(c(reps,ts)))/sd(c(reps,ts))))`, so maybe you think we use `abs(ts-mean(c(reps,ts)))`, it is not true.

Comment: @AdamO That's the right way to do it, because the null hypothesis is that the actual data as well as all the permutations are random partitions of all 35 numbers.  Thus, we include the data along with the permutations for estimating the p-value. That is why you often see people performing $10^k-1$ iterations in their simulations: the numerator then becomes a perfect power of 10.

Answer (score 1):

I think the distribution of the median difference in permutation test does not follow a normal distribution. Here I give some counterexamples.

**First**, choosing $1,\cdots, 20$ as the group data points of 20. Then using permutation test with the median difference and the mean difference between two separate groups, each of which has 10 points. The result is shown in the following figure.[image]
Then we can see that distribution with the median difference is definitely not a normal distribution. It is also important to note that there is no zero in median difference and the smallest value is 1.

**Second**, I random sample 20 points from standard normal distribution. The result of permutation test is shown in the following figure.[image]
**At last**, I random sample 20 points from a uniform distribution. It shows similar. The result of permutation test is shown in the following figure.[image]

In a nutshell, I didn't find that the distribution of the median difference in permutation test follows a normal distribution. I use a Gaussian distribution to fit the distribution of the median difference (black curve), then it is easy to see the difference. 
[image]

Here I post my python code for further discussion.

Thanks.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(color_codes=True)
%matplotlib inline  
import numpy as np
#data = np.linspace(1,20,20) # first case
#data = np.random.randn(20) # second case
data = np.random.rand(20) # last case
print(data)
res_median = []
res_mean = []
for i in range(10000):
    new_data = np.random.permutation(data)
    res_median.append(np.median(new_data[:10]) - np.median(new_data[10:]))
    res_mean.append(np.mean(new_data[:10]) - np.mean(new_data[10:]))

f, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharex=True, sharey=True)

sns.distplot(res_median, 50, label="Median", ax=ax1)
sns.distplot(res_mean, 50, color='green', label="Mean", ax=ax2)
sns.distplot(res_median, 50, label="Median", ax=ax3)
sns.distplot(res_mean, 50, label="Mean", ax=ax3)
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.legend()
plt.savefig('res.pdf')
plt.show()
```